# Using image_picker library to choose gallery photo and take camera pictures

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm totally confused with the use of this library, is this its "most correct" use:

image_picker_service.dart:

```
class ImagePickerService {
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<File?> pickImageFromCamera(BuildContext context) async {
    final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    if (image == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return File(image.path);
  }

  Future<File?> pickImageFromGallery(BuildContext context) async {
    final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (image == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return File(image.path);
  }
}
```

custom_drawer.dart file:

```
import 'package:trilhaapp/service/image_picker_service.dart';

class CustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomDrawer({super.key});

  final ImagePickerService _imagePickerService = ImagePickerService();

  getImageFromCamera(BuildContext context) async {
    var image = await _imagePickerService.pickImageFromCamera(context);
    if (image != null) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }

  getImageFromGallery(BuildContext context) async {
    var image = await _imagePickerService.pickImageFromGallery(context);
    if (image != null) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
```

Down there I'm calling those in a showModalBottomSheet as a ListTile on click like:

```
ListTile(
  leading: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt_rounded),
  title: const Text('Tirar foto'),
  onTap: getImageFromGallery(context),
),
```

Is this making any sense at all? I'd really appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Do you face any problems with using this? Many people use it in many ways. Your approach is also good.

Comment: I cant tell if this works honestly, when I try to run natively it gives me execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

Comment: Please post the complete error message in the question.

Comment: Please refer to this article. It may help you https://medium.com/@dtejaswini.06/mastering-image-compression-and-multiple-image-picker-in-flutter-e06b8cbb156b

Comment: that article really helped, thank you so much!